# php postgres SQL pagination

Tags: php, postgresql, pagination

I need a pagination based on php/postgres.

With the code below, I can break de records but only shows the page 1 (link).

Any idea to fix this?

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 5;
$query = pg_query($dbconn,"select * from my table limit 5 offset 0") or die(pg_result_error($dbconn));
$total_query = pg_num_rows($query);
$total_pages = ceil($total_query / 5);
```

the query result:

```
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($query)){
     ...
}
```

for the pagination:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."' class=\"textPagina\">".$i."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
    }
```

Comment: You can give negative feedback to questions, but at least add something useful to those negative questions so they do not repeat themselves, it would be more helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand your code very well but the basic logic for a pagination sql query is

```
 Select * from pages limit $page_size offset $page_size*($page_no-1);
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

I've fix it.

The code:

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 

$recortds = 10; // change here for records per page

$start_from = ($page-1) * $records;

$qry = pg_query($dbconn,"select count(*) as total from table"); 
$row_sql = pg_fetch_row($qry); 
$total_records = $row_sql[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $records);

$select = pg_query($dbconn,"select * from table limit $records offset $start_from");
```

the select result:

```
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($select )){
    echo $row['col1'].' | '.$row['col2'].' | '.$row['col3'].'<br />';
}
```

the pagination links:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."' class='yourclass'>".$i."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
}
```